# How to create array template in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a template file `config.j2`:

```
 {% for host in groups['dbs'] %}
 ips= {{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
 {% endfor %}
```

My output is:

```
   ips= 192.168.231.91
   ips= 192.168.231.92
   ips= 192.168.231.93
```

I want save in array variable like this:

`ips=['192.168.231.91','192.168.231.92','192.168.231.93']`

How can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
ips=[{{ groups['dbs'] | map("regex_replace", "(.*)", "'\\1'") | join(",") }}]
```

**Explanation**

1. Strings `ips[` and `]` are printed directly in the template;
2. The Jinja2 expression processes the `groups['dbs']` list:

   1. [`map` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) applies a filter (`regex_replace`) to individual elements of the list;
   2. [`regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) surrounds each list element (string) in single quotes;
   3. [`join` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join) converts the resulting list to comma-delimited string in the output.

Comment: thanks. and if i want convert this array to string ? e.g. 
`['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3'] convert to 'ip1,ip2,ip3'`

Comment: Then you need to apply only one of the filters from the answer above.

Comment: please explain more. how to this ? i do a lot filter but don't answer.

Comment: Point no. 2-3 above.